# Monetdb database was killed by signal SIGSEGV

Tags: monetdb

I'have a database version MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v1.1 (Jun2016-SP2) working on RHEL version 6.7
I faced with unexpected shut down with the message in the log: "database was killed by signal SIGSEGV" when trying to execute bunch of 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' quires in single connection. Tables are huge 8Mln rows and 4000 columns.
Also I can't fulfill statistics table for such tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a really old version of MonetDB, I would first upgrade to the latest version. If the problem remains, then file a bug report with enough detail to independent reconstruct the case or sent a stack trace of a debugged version.